# Is this myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE); class object usage good/possible in cpp

Tags: c++

I have created a class object named myFile for a class File which is present in one of my cpp files (FILE.cpp) which I am calling in another file(SDtrail.cpp) where I am working on.

In SDtrail.cpp file I have defined a statement as shown below
    myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

So, my doubt is **can I declare like above statement or not** as I think that this is the root cause of the following errors

error: no match for 'operator=' in 'myFile = SDClass::open(const char*, uint8_t)(((const char*)"test.txt"), 19u)'

error: could not convert 'myFile' to 'bool'

I know that SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE); will provide 1(success) or 0(fail) as output and myFile is an object of my File class ( I have declared it as File myFile). **I don't know whether a class object consists of a type declaration.** 
(FYI: myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE); worked perfectly when I ran that in my Arduino software and when I have printed the myFile variable I got 1 as an output.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible you can do like this. I have declared like this and the code is working perfectly. The reason why I got these errors was because I wasn't giving the file class name properly.